# Rails: Issue with filtering results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to filter results by age and someone on stack was kind enough to suggest a method to do that. In my index action, I have:

```
@users = User.all
@users = User.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", params[:min_age].to_i.years.ago + 1.day, params[:max_age].to_i.years.ago)
```

What I'd like is by default to display all Users and then give the current_user an option to filter by age. But with the code above it is also picking up the second line and filtering the results automatically. The result is that it is filtering Users whose birthday is today or yesterday because there are no params passed in and no users are displayed by default. I'd like some functionality where it does not run the code in the second line above if there are no params passed in or if that is no possible somehow I can have default params if no params are passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
@users = User.all
@users = @users.where("birthday >= ?", params[:min_age].to_i.years.ago + 1.day) if params[:min_age]
@users = @users.where("birthday <= ?", params[:max_age].to_i.years.ago) if params[:max_age]
```

Or perhaps:

```
if params[:min_age] && params[:max_age]
  @users = User.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", params[:min_age].to_i.years.ago + 1.day, params[:max_age].to_i.years.ago)
else
  @users = User.all
end
```

Comment: Sure, the first one is better if you're allowing users to choose just `min_age`, or just `max_age`, or both.